# Openerp make scheduled action

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In openerp there's a standard module named account_followup_print, in here there's a method called do_process which sends out all the payment followup emails.

I want it to automatically do this every day without having to click the button. So I have made the following:

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <record forcecreate="True" id="ir_cron_project_task" model="ir.cron">
        <field name="name">Run Payment Follow-up scheduler</field>
        <field eval="True" name="active"/>
        <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
        <field name="interval_number">1</field>
        <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
        <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
        <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
        <field eval="'account_followup.print'" name="model"/>
        <field eval="'do_process'" name="function"/>
    </record>
</data>
```

Yet this does not work, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
<record id = "ir_cron_project_task" model = "ir.cron">
     <field name="name">Run Payment Follow-up scheduler</field>
     <field eval="True" name="active"/>
     <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
     <field name="interval_number">1</field>
     <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
     <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
     <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
     <field eval="'account_followup.print'" name="model"/>
     <field eval="'do_process'" name="function"/>
     <field eval="'()'" name="args"/>
</record>
```

Comment: If I do that I get the following error: "TypeError: do_process() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)"

Comment: Take the last line setting the args field out all together and you should be fine.  Assuming v7 api your method signature should be def do_process(self, cr, uid, context = None):